# if not img==None: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x

I'am trying to verify if a directory is not empty but ran into an error.
In the code below, where it reads:  `if not img==None:`

```
  img='media/%s' % image
  img=cv2.imread(img)
  if not img==None:
        img=cv2.resize(img,(600,600),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        images.append(img)
        lables.append(int(student.rollNumber))
   else:
        print ("image not found ",student.rollNumber,image)

   return images ,lables
```

Comment: Use `is` when testing against `None`. In this case `if img is not None: ...`

Comment: @Duncan thanks very much i appreciate your help it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to check `if img is not None`. Your current approach will generate an array whose values will be the results of comparing every single value of `img` with `None` (so, you'll get an array filled with zeros and ones). Then, `not <a whole array>` doesn't make much sense because the truth value of an array with more than one value is ambiguous: for example, is `a = array([True, False])` "truthy" or not? It's neither, but `a.any()` and `a.all()` will give a definite answer.